# Table with offset rows

Tags: tables

How can I make a table that looks like this:

[image]

where column 2's values are centered between column 1's values.

Comment: For future consideration: How about giving a table that has the values completed? It'll speed up the consumption of the problem in the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set every column in its own `tabular` - they would necessarily be vertically centred, giving the indication that the output rows are offset:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
  \toprule
  Sample person's data & Cal year & Age & Person-years by stratum \\
  \midrule
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    AAA \\ AAA \\ AAA \\ AAA \\ AAA \\ AAA \\ AAA
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    BBB \\ BBB \\ BBB \\ BBB \\ BBB \\ BBB
  \end{tabular} & 
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    CCC \\ CCC \\ CCC \\ CCC \\ CCC \\ CCC
  \end{tabular} &
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    DDD \\ DDD \\ DDD \\ DDD \\ DDD \\ DDD
  \end{tabular} \\
  \cmidrule{4-4}
  & & & XX
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: impressive! What does booktabs do?

Comment: @Benjamin: Read the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf)! :) The main idea is to avoid excessive horizontal rules, and *never* use vertical rules.